# How do I use a kombu Consumer together with sockjs-cyclone?

Tags: python, websocket, sockjs, kombu

I have various applications pushing messages into RabbitMQ and I want my `sockjs-cyclone` server to consume those messages and push them out to websocket clients. I'd like to use `kombu` as my RabbitMQ consumer library, but I can't figure out where to put my consumer and which parts of `kombu's` consumer interface I should use.

I am stuck on at least the following mental obstacles:

- I apparently need to consume from inside of my `SockJSConnection` so that I have access to `self.sendMessage`
- but I don't think I can use `kombu's` `Connection.drain_events` or `SimpleQueue.get` from anywhere in there because those are synchronous, blocking calls.

Is there a good way to integrate these two libraries?